# Estructura de programa c++

Tags: dev-c++

Buenas no se si alguien puede verificar si la estructura de mi programa esta bien ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre como usar funciones ya que estoy empezando en la programación la idea es hacer un programa que al ingresar la edad diga si una persona es mayor de edad o menor de edad

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int mayorEdad(int edad);

int mayorEdad(int edad){
int edadin
if(edad>=18){
    cout<<"usted es mayor de edad";
}
else if(edad<18){
cout<<"usted es menor de edad ";
}
return edadin;
}
main(){

int ed;
cout<<"ingrese su edad: ";
cin>>ed;
mayorEdad(ed);
retur 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu código, me percaté de varias observaciones, de las cuales son las siguientes:

Cuando inicializas la variable `edadin`, te falta añadir un `;`, es por eso que sale un error en la condición `if` de abajo:

```
int edadin; // <-- aquí
if(edad >= 18) {
  cout<<"usted es mayor de edad";
}
```

En el main, está mal escrito `retur`, tiene que ser `return`:

```
main() {
    int ed;
    cout << "ingrese su edad: ";
    cin >> ed;
    mayorEdad(ed);
    return 0; // <-- aquí
}
```

También, ya no es necesario poner la función arriba:

```
int mayorEdad(int edad); // <-- esto no va

int mayorEdad(int edad)
{
 //...
}
```

---

Arreglando la sintaxis del código, resultaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int mayorEdad(int edad)
{
    int edadin;

    if (edad >= 18)
    {
        cout << "usted es mayor de edad";
    }
    else if (edad < 18)
    {
        cout << "usted es menor de edad ";
    }
    return edadin;
}
main()
{
    int ed;
    cout << "ingrese su edad: ";
    cin >> ed;
    mayorEdad(ed);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// ingrese su edad: 20
// usted es mayor de edad

// ingrese su edad: 15
// usted es menor de edad
```

Comment: Te faltó mencionar que falta el tipo de retorno de `main`. Por cierto, si aún no lo conoces `clang-format` es una buena herramienta de línea de comandos para darle formato al código en varios lenguajes (C, C++, C#, Java y otros más) y te ahorra tiempo.

Comment: No sería mejor que la función mayorEdad retornara un bool, y el if dejarlo en el main ??

Comment: @Mateo lo tendré en cuenta, gracias.

Comment: @Yussef yo sólo corregí los errores de código del OP, podrías sugerírselo al autor.

Comment: Gracias tomare sus sugerencias para seguir aprendiendo

Comment: Hablando de `edadin`, acabo de notar que es una variable sin inicializar. Podría eliminarla y cambiar el tipo de retorno a `void`. O agregar `return true` y `return false` o lo que corresponda y también eliminar la variable ya que el código es más simple sin ella.